# Keeping track of stack size in linked list implementation of a stack C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I am working on a linked list implementation of a stack of ItemType (currently set to double but can be changed) values. Although my code is compiling fine, I have realized that my size method is rather inefficient, as it uses iteration to obtain the size of linked list--O(n) time complexity--when it could simply store size as a field of node, update it within my other methods, then return that value--improving the method so it has O(1) time complexity. Unfortunately, however, I am having some issues figuring out how to integrate this new size field, particularly how to initialize its value, and my compiler keeps telling me it is unable to be edited. My question, then, is how can I implement size as a field of the node class (or should I implement it somewhere else?) and where in my code should I initialize and update it?

Below is my header file for the linked list stack:

```
#ifndef DBLSTACK_H
#define DBLSTACK_H


typedef double ItemType; // stack currently holds doubles


class DblStack
{
private:
    //Node class
    class Node
    {
    public:
        double data;
        Node *next;

        // Node constructor
        Node(double value, Node * link = 0)
        {
            data = value;
            next = link;
        }
    };

    typedef Node * NodePtr;

    // Data members
    NodePtr myTop;  //points to top of stack

  public:
    // Class Constructor
    DblStack();

    // Copy Constructor
    DblStack(const DblStack& rhs);

    // Class Deconstructor
    ~DblStack();

    // Assignment operator
    // Assigns a stack to another
    const DblStack& operator= (const DblStack& rhs);

    // isEmpty
    // Checks if the stack is empty
    bool isEmpty() const;

    // push
    // Pushes an item on top of the stack.
    void push(const ItemType& item);

    // pop
    // Pops the top item off the stack.
    void pop();

    // top
    // Returns the top item of the stack without popping it.
    ItemType top() const;

    // size
    // Returns the number of items on the stack.
    size_t size() const;

};

#endif
```

And here is my source file:

```
#include <cstddef>  //for NULL
#include <stdexcept>
#include "DblStack.h"
using namespace std;

// Class Constructor
DblStack::DblStack()
: myTop(0)
{
}


// Copy Constructor
DblStack::DblStack(const DblStack& rhs)
{
    myTop = 0;
    if (!rhs.isEmpty())
    {
        // Copy first node
        myTop = new DblStack::Node(rhs.top());

        // Set pointers to run through stack
        DblStack::NodePtr lastPtr = myTop;
        DblStack::NodePtr origPtr = rhs.myTop->next;
        while (origPtr != 0)
        {
            lastPtr->next = new DblStack::Node(origPtr->data);
            lastPtr = lastPtr->next;
            origPtr = origPtr->next;
        }
    }
}



// Class Deconstructor
DblStack::~DblStack()
{
    // Set pointers to run through stack
    DblStack::NodePtr curr = myTop, next;
    while (curr != 0)
    {
        next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr = next;
    }
}


// Assignment operator
// Assigns a stack to another
const DblStack& DblStack::operator= (const DblStack& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        this->~DblStack();
        if (rhs.isEmpty())
        {
            myTop = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            DblStack tmp(rhs);  // Call copy constructor
            std::swap(myTop, tmp.myTop);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}


// isEmpty
// Checks if the stack is empty
bool DblStack::isEmpty() const
{
    return (myTop == 0);
}


// push
// Pushes an item on top of the stack.
void DblStack::push(const ItemType& item)
{
    myTop = new DblStack::Node(item, myTop);
}


// pop
// Pops the top item off the stack.
void DblStack::pop()
{
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        DblStack::NodePtr ptr = myTop;
        myTop = myTop->next;
        delete ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::underflow_error("Stack is empty");
    }
}


// top
// Returns the top item of the stack without popping it.
ItemType DblStack::top() const
{
    if (!isEmpty())
    {
        return myTop->data;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::underflow_error("Stack is empty");
    }
}


// size
// Returns the number of items on the stack.
size_t DblStack::size() const
{
    size_t size = 0;
    DblStack::NodePtr ptr;
    for (ptr = myTop; ptr != 0; ptr = ptr->next)
    {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
```

While improving my size method is the main goal of this question, I'd also appreciate any other suggestions you may have for optimizing my code. Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: This should go on CodeReview.SE.

Comment: `this->~DblStack();` ??!! Why? `const DblStack& DblStack::operator= (const DblStack& rhs) { DblStack temp(rhs); std::swap(temp.myTop, myTop); return *this; }`  That is all your operator= needs to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add a *size* member variable to your DblStack class:

```
class DblStack
{
private:
    size_t size;
// ...
}
```

When you first construct a DblStack, it has nothing it in, so its size should be 0:

```
DblStack::DblStack()
    : myTop(0)
    , size(0)
{ }
```

Now you need to think about when the size will change! You should find that the only cases it changes are when items are either pushed or popped from the stack. Consequently, you'll want your push and pop methods to reflect this:

```
// Push increases stack size
size++;

// Pop decreases stack size
size--;
```

Lastly, you can change your size() method to just return the size:

```
size_t size() const { return size; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Include size as a member of `DblStack`, and modify its other methods to keep it up to date.

Comment: "... and modify DblStack's other methods..."

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood second part of your answer.